# Looping with while loop while fetching records from database is not working properly

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Im trying to iterate two arrays simultaneously as follows,

First if countriesIterator has got next element, domain Iterator will be looped.
  CountryIterator has got two elements and domain iterator might contain n elements.
  when Im looping the domainIterator, Im populating an arraylist with values that I have looped.
  and when the loop reaches the country iterator, Im putting the arraylist within a hashmap.

```
  Iterator<String> domainIterator = selectedDomains.iterator();
                    Iterator<String> countriesIterator = selectedCountries.iterator();
                    filteredComplianceCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    inProgressComplianceCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    delayedComplianceCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    nonComplianceCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                    //Looping Countries
                    while (countriesIterator.hasNext()) {
                        String countryKey = countriesIterator.next();
                        Country country = aparjithaDb.getCountryId(countryKey);

                    //Looping Domains
                        while (domainIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Domain domain = aparjithaDb.getDomain(domainIterator.next());
                            int domainId = domain.getDomainId();
                            int countryId = country.getCountryId();

                            //fetch datas from db based on country and domain id/
                            List<ChartData> allChartCDCounts = db.getAllChartCDCounts(countryId, domainId);

                            //iterate the list to get the count values
                            for (ChartData al : allChartCDCounts) {
                                int complied_count = al.getComplied_count();
                                int delayed_compliance_count = al.getDelayed_compliance_count();
                                int not_complied_count = al.getNot_complied_count();
                                int inprogress_compliance_count = al.getInprogress_compliance_count();

                                //add the count values to an arraylist
                                filteredComplianceCount.add(complied_count);
                                delayedComplianceCount.add(delayed_compliance_count);
                                inProgressComplianceCount.add(inprogress_compliance_count);
                                nonComplianceCount.add(not_complied_count);
                            }
                        }

                        //put the arraylist with in hashmap
                        compMap.put(countryKey, filteredComplianceCount);
                        delayedCompMap.put(countryKey, delayedComplianceCount);
                        inProgMap.put(countryKey, inProgressComplianceCount);
                        nonCompMap.put(countryKey, nonComplianceCount);

                    }
```

The problem with my code is that, the key of hashmap remains unique (The keys are two different country names after adding values) but the values remains the same for both keys. The domain Iterator is being invoked only once but it should have been invoked twice because there are two different keys. How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the first iteration of `countriesIterator` you have your `domainIterator` reached the end. You probably should include your `Iterator<String> domainIterator = selectedDomains.iterator();` into `countriesIterator` loop so it started to iterate again from the beginning on the each iteration of `countriesIterator`.

Comment: Now the array looks like Singapore=[13, 4], India=[13, 4] but i want it to be like Singapore[4] , India[13]...

Comment: On each iteration , the values are being embedded to existing array but I want to create new array for each iteration and put them up in a hashmap

Comment: i can't see any comparison of something to something, u just strictly put values one after another. no? Shouldn't you in example compare int domainId to  countryId and proceed only if they are equal?

Comment: Yeah I got it.... I created array list each time and now it works fine..Thank you...